# Declare error in pig script

Tags: hadoop, compiler-errors, apache-pig

```
%declare SOURCEPATH '/user/training/us_records/us-500.csv'  
%declare STOREPATH '/user/training/us_records/us_result.csv'  
table_data = LOAD '/user/training/us_records/us-500.csv' USING     PigStorage(',')  
AS(firstname :CHARARRAY,
lastname :CHARARRAY,
company :CHARARRAY,
address :CHARARRAY,
city :CHARARRAY,
country :CHARARRAY,
state :CHARARRAY,
zip :INT,
phone1: INT,
phone2 :INT,
email :CHARARRAY,
web :CHARARRAY);  
people_sample = GROUP table_data BY (country,state);  
pss = SAMPLE people_sample 0.01;  
STORE pss INTO '$STOREPATH';
```

Result:
    Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: file:/user/training/us_records/us-500.csv

Comment: It clearly says input path: "/user/training/us_records/us-500.csv" does not exist. Did you check, if it exists?

Comment: File is present in hdfs as well as local filesystem.I tried the same script in pig local mode it works fine,to execute the same script in mapreduce mode PIG_CLASSPATH environment variable to the location of the cluster configuration directory has to be set.

Comment: I get this error "ERROR: 2114", only when the path does not exist. One more thing. You are not using SOURCEPATH anywhere in your script.